# Wireless Xbox 360 controller for PC receiver does not automatically turn on after startup

Tags: pc, controllers, windows-8.1

I have Windows 8.1 Pro x64 and have the latest Xbox 360 Accessories 1.2 driver installed. Whenever I boot up my desktop while the receiver is plugged in, the light does not come on, which I'm assuming that the receiver is not on. I have to unplug and plug the receiver back into the USB 3.0 hub in order for it to "turn on".

Are there any workarounds for this? (This did work when I was on Windows 7).

Comment: The same thing happens sometimes on my PC with my wireless mouse when I boot the PC. It's most likely related to Windows; possibly its native USB drivers.

Comment: Are you using an external 'mutitap' hub or is it plugged directly into the PC's USB slots?

Comment: @Robotnik It's plugged directly into a USB hub.

Comment: @Daniel can you try putting it directly into the PC?

Comment: I have this same issue and it seems to be completely random whether or not the receiver will be on at start or not.   I'm wondering if it is an xinput issue or actually related to some service with respect to the receiver itself (which seems strange to me).

Comment: When it doesn't turn on, does it appear as an unrecognized device in the Devices and Printers list?

Answer (score -3):

In order for the controller to 'turn on' the application needs to be open. When you load up the computer open up task manager and search for 'XBoxStat.exe' That needs to be running for the controller to work.

You will need to change the settings to run that program on startup for the controller to turn on on startup.

Comment: I have XboxStat.exe enabled on startup.

Comment: you sure it's running on startup?

Comment: Yes http://i.imgur.com/U1LqGk0.png